# Why doesn't this MySQL event run every day?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE EVENT cleanup_fights_1
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2020-01-12 12:00:00'
    DO
        DELETE f.* 
        FROM fights AS f 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT fighter1,fighter2,COUNT(*) as num_scorecards 
            FROM scorecards 
            WHERE private LIKE 'NO' AND flagged LIKE 'NO' 
            GROUP BY fighter1,fighter2 
            HAVING num_scorecards < 5 
            ORDER BY num_scorecards DESC) AS s 
        ON f.fighter1 = s.fighter1 
            AND f.fighter2 = s.fighter2 
            AND f.date > '2014-05-04';
```

--

```
mysql> show events;
+-------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+------+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Db                | Name             | Definer      | Time zone | Type      | Execute at | Interval value | Interval field | Starts              | Ends | Status  | Originator | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+------+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| rajohns_judgecard | cleanup_fights_1 | rajohns_08@% | SYSTEM    | RECURRING | NULL       | 1              | DAY            | 2020-01-12 12:00:00 | NULL | ENABLED |          0 | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
```

--

```
mysql> show create event cleanup_fights_1;
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Event            | sql_mode                                                                                                                                  | time_zone | Create Event                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| cleanup_fights_1 | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | SYSTEM    | CREATE DEFINER=`rajohns_08`@`%` EVENT `cleanup_fights_1` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2020-01-12 12:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO DELETE f.* FROM fights AS f INNER JOIN (SELECT fighter1,fighter2,COUNT(*) as num_scorecards FROM scorecards WHERE private LIKE 'NO' AND flagged LIKE 'NO' GROUP BY fighter1,fighter2 HAVING num_scorecards < 5 ORDER BY num_scorecards DESC) AS s ON f.fighter1 = s.fighter1 AND f.fighter2 = s.fighter2 AND f.date > '2014-05-04' | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

--

```
mysql> show grants;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for rajohns_08@%                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rajohns_08'@'%'           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `exampleDB`.* TO 'rajohns_08'@'%' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

--

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

If I manually execute the SQL query, it works fine.

Comment: How are you determining that it doesn't run?

Comment: @Schwern, the rows that are deleted by manually running are not deleted every day on schedule.

Comment: What do your server logs say at 12:00:00?

Comment: There's no point in using `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Comment: Trace your event procedure. Create MyISAM debug table. Add BEGIN-END to event proc. Add INSERTs into debug table before and after your DELETE action, in last insert query and save errors table data in addition to checkpoint name. Tomorrow - investigate debug table.

Comment: You can try similar event (same schedule) with a simple insert or delete action on an adhoc table and see what happens - this can help figure if the issue is with the event or the procedural code that it is executing.

Comment: You delete fights, does that mean you have orphan scorecards?

Comment: `ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE` -- hmmm???

Comment: @RickJames That is related to event expiration. This event has no expiration as shown above. But I answered the question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was detailed inside `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

```
2024-01-29T12:00:00.413335Z 1619128 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [rajohns_08@%][rajohns_judgecard.cleanup_fights_1] Thread stack overrun:  3375 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
2024-01-29T12:00:00.413415Z 1619128 [Note] Event Scheduler: [rajohns_08@%].[rajohns_judgecard.cleanup_fights_1] event execution failed.
```

I simply increased `thread_stack` to `256K` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to fix the issue.